# Raw PDF received in Laravel POST Request

Tags: php, laravel, post, request, laravel-8

I am using some APIs that allow a PDF report upload directly on my server.
I'm executing a request, and the remote system reply with a POST request with the PDF file.

Here is my problem:

```
$request->all() //empty
```

Prints:

```
array(
)
```

Instead:

```
$request->getContents()
```

Prints:

```
--ajAJnndaskkASIdjasdasmdadas
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="k7qtpl02srmhe3fnjuzc4wbgd8oa1yv695xi.pdf"
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 3
/Kids [ 3 0 R 4 0 R 5 0 R ]
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Producer (PyPDF2)
/process_id (k7qtpl02srmhe3fnjuzc4wbgd8oa1yv695xi)
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Resources <<
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]
/ExtGState <<
/G3 7 0 R
/G5 8 0 R
>>
/XObject <<
/X7 9 0 R
/X9 10 0 R
/X10 11 0 R
/X11 12 0 R
>>
/Font <<
/F4 14 0 R
/F6 19 0 R
/F8 24 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
```

...and so on. All this strings finish with:

```
-----ajAJnndaskkASIdjasdasmdadas------
```

I need to store this pdf using laravel Storage.
How can i get the $file object?

APIs documentation does not specify any kind of information about the request.

Comment: Does your form include `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu yes it does... Should I specify the boundary too?

Comment: Does `$request->file` also return an empty array?

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu yes :(

Comment: Can you try renaming the field to something other than 'file'. It might be colliding with the `file()` method.

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu i can't because the field name is defined in external API. Is there any way to convert raw obtained from getContents() method?